# Why can't I call class function inside addEventListener

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why am I unable to return the element_id in the run function? The script works if I set it as `let self = this; function(){ self.run() }`

Doesn't work:

```
class clickin {
    constructor(element_id) {
      this.element = document.getElementById(element_id);
      this.element.addEventListener('click', this.run);
    }
    run() {
      alert('Element id: ' + element_id);
    }
}
```

Works:

```
   class clickin {
        constructor(element_id) {
          this.element = document.getElementById(element_id);
          let self = this;

          this.element.addEventListener('click', function(){
            self.run();
          });
        }
        run() {
          alert('Element id: ' + element_id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the fat arrow syntax instead `run = () => { /* do stuff */ };`

Comment: Sublime doesn't like the color, but that works. Why is that? Is it because set() is a anon function?

Comment: no, it's because the ES6 arrow syntax automatically binds methods to instantiated class objects

Comment: @Matt Take a look at this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions .

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the addEventListener object, you are setting a callback function which will be called when the event is fired. So, it runs in a different context than your constructor function. In that case, the "caller(this)" object changes, and thus, this.run you mentioned above won't work.
But, when you assign "clickin" class object to a variable "self", you are able to run because self is available in callback function as a closure, and when event handler executes, it is able to access that "clickin" object.
You might want to look deeper into below topics for better understanding.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, if you don't want to deal with class properties (as mentioned in the comments), just use an arrow function in the constructor instead:

```js
class clickin {
  constructor(id) {
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);
    this.element.addEventListener('click', () => this.run(id));
  }
  run(id) {
    alert('Element id: ' + id);
  }
}

const c = new clickin('a');
```

```html
<div id="a">aaa</div>
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer -- just use an arrow function, and you can call any other functions/methods in the class with the key word "this" INSIDE that arrow function.